# Incrementing DynamoDB number field is not persisted

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with a 'count' Number field.  I'm incrementing the field using AttributeAction.ADD.  It works, but when I re-run my app it does not increment the existing value, instead it starts from '1' again.

I'm expecting:

```
run #1: 1,2,3,4,5
run #2: 6,7,8,9,10
```

Instead I'm seeing:

```
run #1: 1,2,3,4,5
run #2: 1,2,3,4,5
```

What am I doing wrong?  Here is the code I am running in my app:

```
        Map<String, AttributeValueUpdate> updateItems = new HashMap<String, AttributeValueUpdate>();

        Key key = new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS(targetKey));
        updateItems.put("count",
                new AttributeValueUpdate()
                        .withAction(AttributeAction.ADD)
                        .withValue(new AttributeValue().withN("1")));

        ReturnValue returnValues = ReturnValue.ALL_NEW;

        UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest()
                .withTableName(tableName)
                .withKey(key)
                .withAttributeUpdates(updateItems)
                .withReturnValues(returnValues);


        UpdateItemResult result = dynamoDB.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
```

Comment: The code looks fine. What is targetKey? perhaps it's different?

Comment: targetKey is the primary element of the table.  It just a variable passed in to this code.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine.  I tested it another app without any problem.  I reran my first app today and it worked fine again.  There were no code changes since this resides in a shared jar.  I'm guessing that there was an issue with the table that was originally created with my first run.  I'm not sure what since table creation code is inside the same jar and also has not changed.